# Stopwatch Actionscript3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

i'm still new to as3.0. I've been trying to do the milliseconds part and reset button but can't seem to do so. Please help. Here's my code:

```
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, doTimer);
var myTimeNum = 0 ;

function doTimer (e:TimerEvent):void{
    myTimeNum++;
    var myMilliSec = Math.floor(myTimeNum%1000);
    var mySec = Math.floor(myTimeNum%60);
    var myMin = Math.floor(myTimeNum/60%60);
    var myHour = Math.floor(myTimeNum/3600);

}

btnReset.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doReset);
function doReset (e) {

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should call `flash.utils.getTimer()` instead of manually computing time...

Answer (score 0):

Well your reset button doesn't work because you have no code there. It can be as simple as setting the time variable to zero again.

You can't calculate the milliseconds with your current time interval because it's set at one second. You need to set it to the smallest interval that you want to keep track of. In your case you want every millisecond to count so you have to set the timer to `1` instead of `1000`.

Your time divisions aren't correct. Only the millisecond part is correct. You can definitely look up the correct equations on the internet somewhere so I won't try here.